# How to score CVSS for these findings?

Tags: cvss

I am using CVSS 3.1 and even though I read the documentation I still doubting with numerous findings. For example:

1. Internet facing hostname is missing CAA and SPF DNS record. What would PR be? I suppose you need high privileges in order to create a new certificate (missing CAA record), so PR:H? What about CIA?
2. Internet facing web server discloses server version number in HTTP header. This seems pretty simple - CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:L/I:N/A:N. Would this be correct? 5.3 score does seem pretty high for such a innocent finding.
3. SQL Server configuration has "CRL enabled = 1". Does CVSS even apply to such configuration related findings?
4. FTP server is accessible from the Internet on port 21. Can CVSS be used for this? How would it look?

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation about what CVSS is for: https://www.first.org/cvss/v4.0/faq

Comment: @schroeder, I read your link, which part exactly are you referring to? I realize it's vulnerability scoring system and technically some of these are not vulnerabilities, but then even market leading companies often define CVSS for various misconfiguration issues. For example here, CVSS 5.3 score is set for SMB signing enabled: https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/57608.

Comment: That's not the support for your position that you think it is. How does the lack of SPF result in an attack against the server? As an exercise, write up how you would describe each of these in the format of that Nessus plugin.

Comment: First line: "The Common Vulnerability Scoring System (CVSS) is an open framework for communicating the characteristics and severity of software vulnerabilities." You've expanded the scope of the scoring system to vulnerabilities to the org itself beyond the software.

Comment: Fair enough. But then as per my link Tenable also does not define this correctly with their SMB CVSS score?

Comment: First paragraph; "An unauthenticated, remote attacker can exploit this to conduct man-in-the-middle attacks against the **SMB server**." It's a server setting to protect the server. It's not an org-wide issue.

Comment: @schroeder but can't most misconfigurations be present like this? "An attacker can exploit lack of SPF header on the hostname to send malicious email to legitimate users." or "An attacker can exploit Internet-facing FTP server to access sensitive files", and so on.

Answer (score 3):

To me it seems that you struggle with defining what's a vulnerability and what's a feature.

Does reporting versions make a vulnerability? I would argue no; it's not intended to be secret, so why bother? If you're running latest and greatest it should reveal nothing; if 0-days are known, they will work against you anyway, so an attacker doesn't really gain a huge edge. If you run *really* outdated stuff, the problem isn't that an attacker knows that you do; it's the fact that you do that's your problem.

Same goes for things like CRL and FTP servers. If you need CRL support in SQL Server, it's a feature, not a vulnerability. If you don't need it, it extends the attack surface, and should probably be disabled. Same for FTP - if I'm aware that I'm running an FTP server, and it serves stuff I *want* to be public, then it doesn't compromise anything. It's an desired service.

Comment: I guess my confusion arises that everyone seems to be using this differently. For example here Tenable defines CVSS 5.3 score for SMB signing disabled - https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/57608. This is not vulnerability just like DNS config, correct?

Comment: So how do i decide what can be rated using CVSS and what not? It sounds like most findings related to weak configuration then shouldn't have CVSS score assigned or not the case?

Comment: What Schroeder wrote: First line: "The Common Vulnerability Scoring System (CVSS) is an open framework for communicating the characteristics and severity of software vulnerabilities." You've expanded the scope of the scoring system to vulnerabilities to the org itself beyond the software.

Comment: If it is not a vulnerability, it doesn't make sense to score it. A FTP server you're aware of is not a vulnerability. It's a feature.

Comment: Ok, so for example: It makes sense to set CVSS for SSL 3.0 because it's vulnerable to BEAST, but it does not make sense to set CVSS for RC4 because it's a weak cipher but no per se a vulnerability? Likewise it does not make sense to set CVSS for insecure RDP or SMB configuration because it's just a config issue? Even though it clearly  posses a risk. What about detailed error message being disclosed? That sounds like a feature, on the other than i can easily see how can that be defined a vulnerability if it's not intended to be shown.

Comment: Sorry I didn't pick up what you said.

Comment: A config issue *can* create a vulnerability. That vulnerability can be scored.